# converting &lt; and &gt;

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a followig xml data

```
<xml>
  <para> 
  <number>1</number>
             &lt;text class="text"&gt;the cost to the &lt;123; each capital property <a href="none" num="88(1)">88(1)</a> and (1.7) &lt;/text&gt;
  </para>
```

I want to run an xslt script which will give the following output

```
<xml>
  <para> 
  <number>1</number>
             <text class="text">the cost to the &lt;123; each capital property <a href="none" num="88(1)">88(1)</a> and (1.7) </text>
  </para>
 </xml>
```

so bascially replacing `&lt;text class="text"&gt;` with `<text>` and   `&lt;/text&gt;` with `</text>`

I thought of using charter maping like this

```
<xsl:character-map name="a">
<xsl:output-character character="&lt;" string="&lt;"/>
<xsl:output-character character="&gt;" string=">"/>
</xsl:character-map>
```

but problem with this approach is that it converts all `&lt;` into `<` which causing problems where we dont want  to replace it like above `&lt;123;`

Comment: What is the `&lt;123;`? With that there, it becomes much harder for any automated process to distinguish between what's supposed to be XML markup, and what's not.

Comment: What are the logic rules for determining which `&lt;`s you don't want to unescape?

Comment: IF we dont have matching &gt; then ignore it.

Comment: That's a start. How do you know if you don't have a matching `&gt;`? In the above example, how do you know that the `&gt;` at the end of the line doesn't match the `&lt;` preceding `123`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking to do is to add one additional "parse" step, or (sort of equivalently) to remove an "escape" step, for the text nodes containing escaped XML... except for certain `&lt;`s.

The quick-and-dirty way is to remove an "escape" step by using disable-output-escaping (DOE) on those text nodes. You could use a test like "contains(., '<')" to determine which text nodes to unescape during serialization.

*However*, DOE is often **not recommended** for various reasons. One reason is that it's not necessarily portable - XSLT processors aren't required to honor it, and some cannot. Another reason is that you're trying to output XML, while treating it as non-XML text (using a string not a tree). When you do that, there are bound to be mismatches between what you need and what the processor will do.

Also, DOE will not solve the problem that you have some instances of `&lt;` that you don't want to unescape, and others that you do. It would unescape all instances.

A more robust answer would be to have XSLT parse the string into actual XML nodes, then output these. You could theoretically do this in XSLT using `<xsl:analyze-string>`. But you might be better off using a custom extension function that you write in another language (see [here](http://forum.umbraco.org/yaf_postst5730_Parsing-a-string-as-XML-using-XSLT.aspx)). I don't think any existing implementation for parsing XML in XSLT (such as the `saxon:parse()` extension function) is going to work, unless you preprocess your input text, since your input text is not well-formed XML.

In order to implement this successfully, you'll need to specify exactly how to decide whether an `&lt;` in your data should be interpreted as XML markup or not.